# Passing strongly type form model data in asp.net mvc through jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

It is easy to submit form to an action method in the controller which has strongly typed textboxes for example, with a submit button, but what if I want to send the exact same form with the strongly typed textboxes through jquery perhaps the $.ajax call after something else has been clicked.

code like this:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.topTenFav.YoutubeLink,new { id="youTubeLinkTxt"})
```

does all the work for us and it's very simple to map the properties of our object in the controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddTopTenFav(HomeViewModel topTen)
 {
     topTen.topTenFav.Date = DateTime.Now;
     topTen.topTenFav.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
     repository.AddTopTen(topTen);
     repository.Save();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

How would I send this form to the controller, map the textboxes in the form to object's properties on a click event such as

```
 $("#btnAddGenre").click(function () {}

 @using (Html.BeginForm(
        "AddTopTenFav", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "AddTopTenFavForm" }))
 {

    <span id="youTubeLinkSpan">Youtube Link</span>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.topTenFav.YoutubeLink,new { id="youTubeLinkTxt"})
    </div>
    <span id="youTubeNameSpan">Song Title</span>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.topTenFav.Title,new { id="youTubeNameTxt"})
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="">submit</button>
 }
```

Comment: why have you put an form inside a anonymous function that fires on a click event?

Comment: after reviewing your code in more detail I noticed that you had just forgot to close the click function, regarding being able to do an ajax call, asp.net mvc has an helper Ajax.BeginForm, that way you can use the built in support if you so please.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following post:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnAddGenre').click(function () {
        $.post(
            $('#AddTopTenFavForm').attr('action'),
            $('#AddTopTenFavForm').serialize,
            function (data) {
                window.location = @Url.Action("Index");
            },
            'html' // returned data type
        );
    });
});
```

I use the html data type so you can return whatever you want and the redirect occurs on the `window.location` using the `@Url.Action` to give the location.

**Please if it work mark as accepted answer**

Comment: You put the javascript inside your view. I've changed a little bit. Try again and tell me what happened.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can post the data of strongly typed textboxex using jquery.
First you have to do 
take the values of all the textboxex in jquery using the below code.

```
            var xx= $("#xx").val();
```

this will give the val in xx from your mvc text box.
Then by using jquery ajax call you can call the action method.
the code is below.

```
$.get("/XXXX/YY/1", { xxName: xx }, function (data) {
                    var status = data;
                    alert(status);
                    if (status) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("The book with this name is already present. TRY DIFFERENT NAME!")
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

here xxxx is controller amd yy is action method name.the next parameter is the value of all the textboxes which you want to send as an parameter.
This will perform the ajax call and return the value.

Please tell me if you find any problem the i will give the whole code.

Comment: Nice solution. You're assuming he is returning true from the controller and creating manually all the parameters you want to pass trough the get request.

Comment: No I assume that as he is working in MVC3 with razor, then I think he can understand what he needs get or post . so he can manipulate it acc. to his requirement.As I have copy and pasted the jquery code so by mistake i forget to change it to post.
And for the parameter you can take parameter in jquery and can easily send the values in the post method using this process.
You can try this method as it is very easy
And thanks for alerting me for my mistake
thanks

Comment: sorry for not answering but this didnt really work for me. I found a  working solution to mz problem                                        $.post("/Home/AddTopTenFav", $("#AddTopTenFavForm").serialize(), function(json) {
              // handle response
          }, "json");